# bit manipulation

Tags: c++

I am playing around with bits trying to get a sound understanding of it and I came across this problem. I am setting the sixth bit in the char to a 1 and I am trying to find out if the it actually being set to a 1. It's giving me a wrong answer.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    unsigned char a=0;
    a=a | (1<<6);
    int b=a &(1<<6);
    cout<< b;
    return 0;
}
```

It's giving me a result of 64 rather than 1. Why?

Comment: Why should it give you 1? In your mind, what do you think `&` does?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. 2^6 = 64

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the correct and intended behaviour.

The way to check whether bit `n` is set is like this:

```
return (value & (1U << n)) == (1U << n);
```

The `&` performs *bitwise* AND, so `11111111 & 01000000` is `01000000`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int b = (a >> 6) & 1;
```

`b` will be `== 1` if the sixth bit is set and `0` if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output of your program is 64 because `64&64` is 64.  Since non-zero values are interpreted as true in `if` expressions and conditional operators (`&&`, `||`), that's good enough for a lot of cases:

```
a |= (1<<6);
if (a & (1<<6))
{
    /* this code would get executed */
}
```

If you're bothered by having 64s in your variables, then try something like this:

```
bool b = (a & (1<<6)) ? true : false;
```

I'm not sure if the ternary operator is needed here, but is makes it very clear what is happening.

Or you could probably do this:

```
bool b = a >> 6 & 1;
```